# Looping over list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I started learning python few weeks ago, with no programming background so far.
I was wondering if somebody could explain me in plain words, what does the "Looping over list" does?
Here is the example:

```
list = [4, 'b', 'e',21,5]
for n in list:
    print n
```

After running the script, what I get is: list being printed item by item:
4
b
e
21
5

But I do not understand the logic behind it.
Would somebody be kind to explain it to me?

Thank you, and sorry for ignorance.

Comment: what do you want to know exactly? it just move through your list (from zero index to end) and print five you the elements

Comment: Some reading may help: [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), [python tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm), [hands on python](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/loops.html#basic-for-loops).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your example makes it about as clear as you can ask for.

```
mylist = [4, 'b', 'e', 21, 5]
```

By using the `[` syntax, this creates a new [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), and initializes it with the items given, in the order they are given in.  The list is then assigned to the variable `mylist`. (Note that I changed the name, because `list` is the default name of the `list` datatype).

```
for n in mylist:
```

This is a [for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop), that iterates over all items in the list.  Python strives to be read like English. So it says,

> for every item in the list `mylist`, call the item `n` and do the following:

Then, everything that is indented under the `for`, is executed for each item.

```
print n
```

Of course, this prints `n` to the screen.

---

So in conclusion, your code says:

> 1) Create a list with the following items: 4, 'b', 'e', 21, 5
>
> 2) For every item in that list, call it `n`, and then print `n` to the screen.

- [Python `for`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: But how does Python know that "n" is the iteration variable (can I call it like that)? I do not understand. This code seems to do the same thing, and it is perfectly clear to me, in comparison with the one in the starting post:
    list = [4, 'b', 'e',21,5]  for n in range(len(list)):      print list[n]

Btw, sorry for not being able to post the code properly.

Comment: How does it know? Because you specified it! It's part of the [`for` syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for). You could use any variable name you wanted there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to had no exposure to other programming languages, you cannot really see, why this is really a useful notation to express the iteration over the elements of a list.

To contrast it, here's an example from another, more lower level language:

```
int foo[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(foo) / sizeof(int); i++)
{
   printf("%d", foo[i]);
}
```

Basically Python lists are like arrays with a lot of syntactic convenience added to them. That is, you can express something that you'll need often, like iteration, in a much more compact form:

```
somelist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for element in somelist:
    print(element)
```

---

Edit: Sometimes it helps to look at the source, in this case the file `Objects/listobject.c` of a Python source distribution (e.g. 3.3). There you'll find the implementation of all python list methods, among which there is `listiter_next`, which handles traversal. Stripped of a few things, the code looks like this:

```
static PyObject *
listiter_next(listiterobject *it)
{
    PyListObject *seq;
    PyObject *item;

    seq = it->it_seq;
    if (seq == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
        ++it->it_index;
        return item;
    }

    it->it_seq = NULL;
    return NULL;
}
```

You could say that this is *what looping over a list does*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Moj.
But in that case I do not understand the difference upper code and this one (as it seem to get the same result):
    list = [4, 'b', 'e',21,5]
    for n in range(len(list)):
        print list[n]

Comment: Maybe it is enough to see for the moment, that the python version is shorter and more readable.

Comment: @miku haha I doubt showing the CPython code will help OP to understand the logic behind a for loop

Comment: @jamylak, no it won't help, but sometimes I see people thinking there is some kind of magic going on, when in actuality there is not (or mostly not ;).

Answer (score 1):

Think of

```
for x in list:
    print x
```

as the sentence

> For each item x in the list, print (display) what it is.

In another case

```
for x in list:
    print x+1
```

you can read it as

> For each item x in the list, print the result of the item+1.

In terms of the phrase "loop over a list," think of "looping over" as "examining from outside of."  Metaphorically: You're in a plane, flying over a set of buildings:

```
buildings = ['Empire State', 'Chrysler', 'Masonic Lodge']

for building in buildings:
   print "Just flew over the %s building." % building
```

You're repeating a task (in a loop) "over" or "for each" in an array of items, which in the metaphoric case, an array of buildings.

Answer (score 0):

This "looping over list" just goes over each element present on the list (in your example these elements are `4`, `b`, `e`, `21`, `5`) so that you can perform some action on them individually (e.g. `print` or show its value as in your example).

To put this in other words, when you execute this code:

```
for element in list:
    print element
```

it would be the same to instruct the following to a person:

```
for each element pertaining to an array X:
    show me the value of the N-th element from X (X[N])
```

Of course you could do other actions than just "show" each element's value. You could loop over that list and modify the values in (almost) every way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list with a certain number of elements. Now you want to do something with each element in that list, for example, printing it to the console. By using `for n in list` you consider the elements in `list` one by one, and the element currently considered is called `n`. First, `n` refers to the first element in `list`, then to the second, then to the third, and so on. In the indented block below that line, you describe what you want to happen for each element `n`. In this case, the only instruction is to `print` it.